# Vectorization in R with double for

Tags: r, for-loop, vectorization, apply

I've been practicing with R for 1 year and now I'm facing with a new problem called: **vectorization**. Basically I want my code to be faster.
Here's my problem:
I have a matrix with 0 and 1 and I want to compare each row with the other rows to find matches in the same position.
For example, my matrix is: `a<-matrix(c(1,1,1,0,1,1,0,1,0,1,0,1,0,0,0),5,3)`. In this case the first and second row have one match, the first and the third three matches. I want to build a symmetric matrix row-dimensional and in each place write the sum of matches, with 0 on the diagonal.

The code I wrote is:

```
a<-matrix(sample(c(0,1), size=18, replace=T), ncol=3) # a random matrix 6x3

mat<-diag(0,nrow=dim(a)[1])

n<-dim(a)[1]

for( i in 1:(n-1)){
   for (j in (i+1):n){
       mat[i,j]<-sum(ifelse(a[i,]==a[j,],1,0))
    }}
```

I'm looking for something to improve this code and delete the for cycles.
I was on apply but it works with everything but the second-last row and the last one:

```
for( i in 1:(n-2)){
   vv<-a[(i+1):n,]
   mat3[i,(i+1):n]<-apply(vv,1,function(x) sum(ifelse(x==a[i,],1,0)))
}
```

I had to put 2 instead of 1 in the for cycle cause **apply** works only with matrices and not arrays (in fact in the end vv will be an array).
Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

How about this...

```
a <- matrix(c(1,1,1,0,1,1,0,1,0,1,0,1,0,0,0), 5, 3)

b <- apply(a, 1, function(r) apply(a, 1, function(s) sum(r==s)))
diag(b) <- 0

b
     [,1] [,2] [,3] [,4] [,5]
[1,]    0    1    3    1    3
[2,]    1    0    1    1    1
[3,]    3    1    0    1    3
[4,]    1    1    1    0    1
[5,]    3    1    3    1    0
```

Answer (score 1):

Not sure if this is faster than your method, but here is how I would approach it. First, come up with a list of all of the combinations you would want.

```
coms <- combn(1:nrow(a), 2) # combn from utils package
coms
#     [,1] [,2] [,3] [,4] [,5] [,6] [,7] [,8] [,9] [,10]
#[1,]    1    1    1    1    2    2    2    3    3     4
#[2,]    2    3    4    5    3    4    5    4    5     5
```

So, the first column will compare 1 to 2, the second column 1 to 3, etc.

Now, write a function to calculate the number of elements in common given vector length 2 indicating the row indices.

```
funky <- function(com){
  sum(a[com[1], ] == a[com[2], ])
}
funky(c(1, 2))
# [1] 1
funky(c(1, 3))
# [1] 3
```

Now apply this function to the matrix of combinations.

```
apply(coms, 2, funky)
# [1] 1 3 1 3 1 1 1 1 3 1
```

If you prefer this in your matrix output

```
mat <- diag(0, nrow = nrow(a))
mat[lower.tri(mat, diag = FALSE)] <- apply(coms, 2, funky)
t(mat)
#      [,1] [,2] [,3] [,4] [,5]
# [1,]    0    1    3    1    3
# [2,]    0    0    1    1    1
# [3,]    0    0    0    1    3
# [4,]    0    0    0    0    1
# [5,]    0    0    0    0    0
```

Comment: This is definitely faster than the `for` loop. On a 100x100 matrix, it's about 4 times faster.  It seems to perform better using `sum(a[com[1], ] == a[com[2], ])`, but only by a few milliseconds.

Comment: Thanks @Benjamin. You're right, not only should that be slightly faster, but it's easier to read and understand. I've updated my answer with your suggestion.

Answer (score 1):

You could simply do `tcrossprod(a) + tcrossprod(1 - a)`